# how to fetch all the records from one table as XML datatype to another column of second table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to fetch all the records from one table as XML datatype and store it in   another column of second table.

I have two columns that will match these two tables for joining, reportid and exchange.

Should I have to use ID logic or please help me with this logic.

sample :

```
DECLARE @VAL XML
    SET @VAL =  (   
 SELECT 
                     [ID]                           AS [ID]                                 
                    ,[EventType]                    AS [EventType]                          
                    ,[ClientMsgID]                  AS [ClientMsgID]                            
                    ,[SessionID]                    AS [SessionID]                          
                    ,[Protocol]                     AS [Protocol]   
                    FROM TableA O
                    JOIN Tableb T
                    ON O.[ReportID] = T.ReportID 
                    where o.[exchange] = t.exchange
                    FOR XML  PATH ('row'))

insert into TableC
select ID,record_no,@VAL,null,getdate()
from TableA
```

Comment: Please add some sample data, and show what you've tried so far

Comment: @hkravitz i have addded please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not provided enough details on your table design.

If I understood correctly, you want to update table with `XML` from another table, for this you can try like following.

```
UPDATE ST
SET ColumnToStoreXml=(select  * from FristTable FT 
                             where FT.ColumnToMatch=ST.ClumnToMatch for xml PATH ('row') )
FROM SecondTable ST
```

**Edit:**  After the update in the question.

If you want to insert into a new table, try like following.

```
INSERT INTO tablec 
SELECT id, 
       record_no, 
       (SELECT [id]          AS [ID], 
               [eventtype]   AS [EventType], 
               [clientmsgid] AS [ClientMsgID], 
               [sessionid]   AS [SessionID], 
               [protocol]    AS [Protocol] 
        FROM   tablea O 
               JOIN tableb T 
                 ON O.[reportid] = T.reportid 
        WHERE  o.[exchange] = t.exchange 
               AND O.id = T1.id 
        FOR xml path ('row')), 
       Getdate() 
FROM   tablea T1
```

**Note**: It's always a good practice is to use column names in your insert like

```
insert into tablec(col1,col2,col3)
select col1,col2,col3 from sometable
```

Comment: i have to insert 3rd table as a new record  using the two tables A and B.
3rd table has a xml column .